# Где в файлах ядра найти код usb порта Linux?

Tags: linux, c, kernel, posix

Мне стало интересно как устроено ядро Linux и поэтому я нашёл и скачал исходник ядра. Решил начать с чего-то простого и выбрал порт(type c). В исходниках я нашёл две директории с названием usb
1)D:\kernel\linux-4.14.180\linux-4.14.180\tools\usb
2)D:\kernel\linux-4.14.180\linux-4.14.180\drivers\usb\typec
Моя первоначальная цель "найти участок кода в котором будет момент подключение usb-с порта с кабелем". Но чтобы найти участок этого кода мне надо узнать в каком файле это описывается и первое, что я бы хотел узнать, это какая директория с файлами "tools"или"drivers"?  А так же за что отвечают эти директории?

Comment: Неужели названия каталогов не говорят сами за себя. tools это различные утилиты, которые в самом ядре не используются. Да и содержимое каталога как бы намекает что там утилиты тестирования работы usb. А drivers соответственно "драйвера", т.е. поддержка устройств ядром

Comment: Спасибо. Я догадывался, но решил уточнить. Значить нужно искать ответы в drivers. Тут у меня вопрос небольшой, что такое wcove (typec_wcove.c)?

Comment: Там же в начале файла комментарий написан "WhiskeyCove PMIC USB Type-C PHY driver". Кроме того в файле Kconfig (Описание пунктов меню для настройки сборки) ему посвящена опция, в которой более подробно написано "This driver adds support for USB Type-C detection on Intel Broxton
   platforms that have Intel Whiskey Cove PMIC. The driver can detect the
   role and cable orientation"